# SwiftUI fit contents in Rectangle

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am working on the UI for a sign-up page in SwiftUI. I am trying to fit everything in a Rectangle shape but for some reason, the contents keep sticking out of the Rectangle.

[image: Current Page]

As you can see, I want to get the text and TextFields all inside the Rectangle and move them upward a bit, but I am having trouble doing so.

Here's my code for it:

SignUpView.swift

```
struct SignUpView: View {
    @State private var name = ""
    @State private var email = ""
    @State private var username = ""
    @State private var password = ""
    @State private var phoneNumber = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.clear)
                        .frame(width: 358, height: 686)
                        .background(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(16)
                        .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.08), radius: 20, x: 0, y: 6)
                        .overlay(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                                .inset(by: 0.5)
                                .stroke(Color(red: 0.88, green: 0.88, blue: 1), lineWidth: 1)
                        )
                    
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Personal Information")
                                .font(
                                    Font.custom("Work Sans", size: 18)
                                        .weight(.semibold)
                                )
                                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.12, green: 0.12, blue: 0.12))
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                            Text("Step 1")
                                .font(Font.custom("Work Sans", size: 14))
                                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.1, green: 0.68, blue: 1))
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal, 24)
                        
                        TextField("Enter your full name", text: $name)
                            .modifier(TextFieldModifier())
                        
                        TextField("Enter your email", text: $email)
                            .autocapitalization(.none)
                            .modifier(TextFieldModifier())
                        
                        TextField("Enter your username", text: $username)
                            .modifier(TextFieldModifier())
                        
                        TextField("Enter your password", text: $password)
                            .modifier(TextFieldModifier())
                        
                        TextField("Enter your phone number", text: $phoneNumber)
                            .modifier(TextFieldModifier())
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .padding(.top, 60) // Adjust the top padding as needed
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TextViewModifier.swift

```
struct TextFieldModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .font(.subheadline)
            .padding(12)
            .background(Color(.white))
            .cornerRadius(10)
    }
}
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you want the fields _inside_ the `Rectangle`, better to not use a `ZStack` and instead set the `Rectangle` as a background to the stack of fields.

Comment: What about if I need more space in the Rectangle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify the structure by applying the rounded rectangle as a background to the `VStack`, instead of using a `ZStack`. A background layer automatically adopts the size of the view it is applied to, so there is no need to apply a fixed size. It also makes it easier to see how the padding works.

Maybe like this:

```swift
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
            // content as before
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        .padding(.top, 60) // Adjust the top padding as needed
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .background {
            Color.white
                .cornerRadius(16)
                .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.08), radius: 20, x: 0, y: 6)
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                        .inset(by: 0.5)
                        .stroke(Color(red: 0.88, green: 0.88, blue: 1), lineWidth: 1)
                )
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

[image: Background]

Comment: I see. What about if I need more space in the Rectangle such as to put a button at the bottom of the Rectangle and to add Segmented Progress Bars above the Personal Information and Step 1 texts, as well as space between each textfield?

Comment: For more space at the bottom you just need to add bottom padding to the ```VStack```. You can also add more content to the ```VStack``` if it is needed - the size of the background is determined by the contents of the ```VStack```.

Comment: Oh okay. I just added a Spacer to the bottom of the ```VStack``` so that I can have more space but saw it made the rectangle take up too much of the screen, so I'll go with your method. Thanks!